# rvest working previously now returning empty content

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

The following rvest script was working previously, downloading the data as expected. However, after testing if a few times in a for loop, it seems to have stopped working. Is there a problem with the script or is it possible I overscraped the website and have been blocked?

```
single_job <- read_html("https://www.higheredjobs.com/search/details.cfm?JobCode=177182074&Title=Student%20Success%20Coordinator") #job link

job_name <- html_nodes(single_job,'h1') %>% html_text()
job_inst <- single_job %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="jobAttrib"]/div[2]/div[2]') %>% html_text()
job_cat <- single_job %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="jobAttrib"]/div[3]/div[2]/text()') %>% html_text()
job_posted_date <- single_job %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="jobAttrib"]/div[4]/div[2]') %>% html_text()
job_type <- single_job %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="jobAttrib"]/div[6]/div[2]') %>% html_text()
job_body <- single_job %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="jobDesc"]') %>% html_text()

single_job_data <- data.frame(job_name, job_inst, job_cat, job_posted_date, job_type, job_body)
```

Comment: Stopped working how exactly? I ran this code and got a 1x6 data frame for `single_job_data`

Comment: Yes, that worked for me at first. But after running it several times, it began to give errors (empty content). I think the website thinks I am a bot.

Comment: Running your code as is, I get an empty df.

Answer (score 0):

Seems nothing is wrong with code. HigherEdJobs is strict on bots and crawling.